# How to get to text app settings?

Tags: 20.04

I changed my Ubuntu theme to dark theme. Now how do I change my text editor selection to other than white?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, please edit your question and provide more details, which text editor do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the text editor that comes with the system:

1. Open your text editor
2. Click the **Preferences option** which is In the upper right corner
3. Click **Fonts&Colours option**
4. Then choose your **colour scheme**

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)